# NSNotificationCenter may not respond to removeObject

Tags: objective-c

Why show semantic issue?

**NSNotificationCenter may not respond to removeObject**

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [myTableView release];
    myTableView = nil;
    _refreshHeaderView=nil;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObject:self];

    [super viewDidUnload];

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is exactly as the error says. `NSNotificationCenter` doesn't have a method called `-removeObject:`. It sounds like you're looking for `-removeObserver:`. Do note that as of iOS 6, `-viewDidUnload` isn't called, and you shouldn't be doing this kind of thing there.